# Is there an OOP convention about private method signatures - directly using fields or getting arguments?

Tags: oop, methods, field, private, convention

I'd like to know which of the following is a better OOP practice when having private methods. Should the fields be used directly, or given to the method like an argument?

```
class MyClass {
    private int myNumber;

    public MyClass(int number) {
        this.setMyNumber(number);
    }

    public void setMyNumber(int number) {
        this.myNumber = number;
    }

    public int getMyNumber() {
        return this.myNumber;
    }

    public int getTransformedNumber() {
        return transformNumberInSomeWay1();
        // OR 
        return transformNumberInSomeWay2(this.getMyNumber());
    }

    private int transformNumberInSomeWay1() {
        int number = this.getMyNumber();

        <... transformation of the number ...>

        return number;
    }

    private int transformNumberInSomeWay2(int number) {
        <... transformation of the number ...>

        return number;
    }
}
```

If I'm using the transformation number method for other things than the field myNumber, the second way is better. What about the case when I'm not actually using it for anything else, yet I don't know how will the development of the class go? Should I always do it the second way or let the people who need it, change it later on?

Comment: I would omit the private transformNumberInSomeWay method and implement the logic in the getTransformedNumber() method. Then its obvious that you have to omit the parameter and access the variable within the function.

Comment: This would be up to you, there are no hard and fast rules, you are correct in saying the second way would make it easier to abstract/refactor/pull it out later on. But of course you can't know if you will need to do that. Next thing  that is going to drive you mad is should you be using a Command Pattern instead of individual parameters...